Custom wait function only working with a System.out.print call?
I'm currently working on a small game framework with Java AWT and Swing but I'm having a bit of a problem. I have a stable game loop going in a separate thread and would not like to implement a method for other threads to wait until the next "tick", or next render, is performed. I have something that's working with a while loop but I noticed something very odd: it only seems to work when I have a some sort of complicated function call in the while loop like a call to a constructor or a System.out.print call.
Here's my code for the wait function:
public void waitForTick(){
    int lastTick = this.TickCount; //TickCount is a variable keeping track of the total renders that have happened
    while (this.TickCount == lastTick) {
           //Here's the different methods I've tried:
           System.out.print(""); // works with only this
           new String(); //also works with only this, any constructor seems to work
           ; //just a semicolon doesn't work
           int x = 1; //just a variable assignment doesn't work
    }
}

You might be wondering what I mean by "not working" and by that I mean that the while loop just never exits in the cases I described that don't work. I'm so incredibly confused about this, so any help would be great.

Look up "tight loops" which is what you have without the println. This tight loop will starve your code of CPU use unless you put in a println or other code that allows the CPU to yield to other threads.

Thank you! I've fixed this by just waiting a couple milliseconds with Thread.sleep() inside the loop body.

I've taken a look at the duplicate thread above and this has now fixed a huge lag issue I've had in my game for very long, thank you so much!
